# Django maintain order of internal query in external query?

Tags: python, django

I have a profile model which refers to the default User model of Django. I want a list of users with increasing points.

My Profile Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=None, primary_key=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.username
```

I am firing this query:

```
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=Profile.objects.filter().order_by('-points').values('username__username'))
print(users,Profile.objects.filter().order_by('-points').values_list('username__username'))
```

And my output is

```
<QuerySet [<User: aplha>, <User: baqir>, <User: beta>]> <QuerySet [{'username__username': 'beta'}, {'username__username': 'baqir'}, {'username__username': 'aplha'}]>
```

Now here we see, Profile model is giving the usernames in the same order that I want to, but the user model is not maintain that order. How to I make it maintain the same order as the Profile returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

users = User.objects.annotate(points=Sum('profile__points')).order_by('-points')
```

This is untested but I hope it helps!

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'profile_set' into field. Choices are: answer, by, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, on, password, post, profile, question, user_permissions, username, view, vote`

Comment: Can you give me a brief explanation? I accepted your answer. Thanks

Comment: @BaqirKhan `__in` does not guarantee that the order will be preserved. Because, the model `User` has its own ordering. That's why, you need to "annotate" the field you need to the `User` model itself and then sort by that field. In your case, that annotation is the sum of related `points` field.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `_in`, there is not guarantee of the order of the results.

You could fetch the list of users by looping through the profiles. If you use `select_related()` then you will avoid extra queries to fetch each user.

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter().order_by('-points').select_related('username')
users = [p.username for p in profiles]
```

Note that it might be better to rename the foreign `username` foreign key to `user`, since following the foreign key returns a `User` instance, not the `username` string.